# JFace TableViewer get visible column width

Tags: java, swt, scrollbar, jface, tableviewer

I have a `TableViewer` with horizontal scrollbar. Moving the scrollbar or re-sizing window can hide or show certain columns.

I want to know if a certain column is visible after scrolling and if so, its exact width that is visible.

Any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to query the underlying `Table` (`viewer.getTable()`) and its `TableColumn`s (`table.getColumns()`) to solve this.

If you defined the viewers columns using `TableViewerColumn`s the columns are also accessible through `viewerColumn.getColumn()`.

To determine the rightmost visible column, you can use the width of the table's clientArea (`Table#getClientArea().width`) that gives you the total available space to show columns.

Each column has a width `TableColumn.getWidth()`. Adding all the widths of the columns that are left of the desired one, will enable you to dermine if it is visible.

`table.getHorizontalBar().getSelection()` gives you the horizontal offset of the rows. When substracting this offset you should be able to dermine if a given column is visible.

The resulting code would look like this:

```
boolean isColumnVisible(Table table, int columnIndex) {
  int columnRight = 0;
  for( int i = 0; i <= columnIndex; i++ ) {
    columnRight += table.getColumn(i).getWidth();
  }
  int clientAreaWidth = table.getClientArea().width;
  int horizontalOffset = table.getHorizontalBar().getSelection();
  return columnRight - horizontalOffset <= clientAreaWidth;
}
```

Note that if the columns can be re-ordered you need to determine the actual `columnIndex` through `table.getColumnOrder()`

Comment: Great detailed answer! I only needed the offset since my column is at index 0. Thanks a lot.